PnP Charts datapromise error
Im getting this error with the datapromise for a PnP chart

this is the delaration of the chart 
And this is the method thats being called
 private _loadAsynData1():Promise<ChartData>  {

return new Promise<ChartData>((resolve,reject) => {
  const datas: ChartData = {
    labels: ['tttt','rrrrr'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label:'Status',
        data: [2,3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        ],

      }
    ]

  }
  resolve(datas);
})

}
Any help would be appreciated, ive been stuck on this for the past 2 days.
